# Problem with forget plot in the 1.12 version?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

If you comment the line `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}`of this MWE:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[width=10cm,height=8cm, scale only axis,  axis x line=middle,axis y line=middle, samples=300, disabledatascaling, enlargelimits, 
xmin=-2,xmax=2,xtick={-2,-1.5,...,2}, xticklabels={$-\dfrac{2\pi}{T}$, $-\dfrac{1{,}5\pi}{T}$, $-\dfrac{\pi}{T}$, $-\dfrac{\pi}{2T}$, ,$\dfrac{\pi}{2T}$, $\dfrac{\pi}{T}$, $\dfrac{1{,}5\pi}{T}$, $\dfrac{2\pi}{T}$}, xlabel={$\omega$}, 
ymin=0,ymax=5.25,ytick={2.5,5},yticklabels={$T/2$, $T$}, ylabel={$P(\omega)$}, y tick label style={yshift=0.2cm},  
legend style={draw=white, at={(1,1)}, anchor=north east},legend cell align=left]

%alpha=0
\addplot [line width=1pt, color=blue, domain=-5:5, xscale=1, yscale=5]  (-1,0) -- (-1,1) -- (1,1) -- (1,0) ;
\addlegendentry{$\alpha=0$};

%alpha=0.5
\addplot [line width=1pt, color=red, domain=-1.5:-0.5, xscale=1, yscale=5, forget plot=true] {0.5*(1+cos(deg(-x*pi-0.5*pi)))} -- (0.5,1);
\addplot [line width=1pt, color=red, domain=0.5:1.5, xscale=1, yscale=5] {0.5*(1+cos(deg(x*pi-0.5*pi)))} ;
\addlegendentry{$\alpha=0.5$};

%alpha=1
\addplot [line width=1pt, color=black, domain=-2:2, xscale=1, yscale=5] {0.5*(1+cos(deg(0.5*pi*x)))} ;
\addlegendentry{$\alpha=1$};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

the result is very different: it's bad. Any help?

This is the newest result:
[image]

And this is the oldest:[image]

Comment: I find no differences using `compat=newest`, `compat=1.12` or `compat=1.10`. Can you post a picture to help us see the problem more clearly?

Comment: @darthbith I have added the pictures.

Comment: I'm sorry, I cannot reproduce that strange behavior! Can you post the version of pgfplots that you use?

Comment: @darthbith: I use the 1.12 version

Comment: @jpayansomet Which engine are you using? There was a release very recently of 1.12.1 which lists as one change a fix for a problem with LuaTeX and `forget plot`.

Comment: @joseph Wright: In fact I use Luatex and 1.12 version. Maybe it can be the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a known but with `pgfplots` version 1.12, the `forget plot` option and LuaTeX. This is fixed in version 1.12.1 which has been released to CTAN and will presumable be available in TeX Live 2015 and MiKTeX 2.9 in due course.